# J2ME - Wireless Toolkit to create Custom Device

Tags: java, java-me, midp, j2mepolish, java-wireless-toolkit

How can I create custom device emulators using the java wireless toolkit ? I have tried updating the properties file for a new device but when I update the screen size I cannot resize the screen to more than the size of the emulator (320x240 - defaultColorPhone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out MicroEmu. It can work with various resolutions and has good support for most of the JSR's
http://www.microemu.org

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to find native emulator of your target device. By the way what handset do you try?

Comment: To test the full functionality then I would agree, but just to test look and feel with limited time I think a generic emulator is the best way to go. Thanks for comment

Comment: Yes, for testing L&F you just need any emulator with the same screen size. But standard emulators have concrete skin with special space for screen. And I don't know what would be the behavior of emulator if you try to draw outside this space. And however what device emulator do you need?